# LINQ TO Entities: Handling Includes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

probably you have a solution. First of all its just a thought of mine, but I guess we will run in some problems in the future:
We have a businessfacade, which handles the context call with an filter expression, let's say this:

```
    List<INDIVIDUAL> IIndividual.GetIndividuals(Expression<Func<INDIVIDUAL, bool>> filterExpression)
    {
        List<INDIVIDUAL> result = null;
        this.FacadeAction(ctx =>
            {
                result = (filterExpression != null
                              ? ctx.INDIVIDUALs.Where(filterExpression)
                              : ctx.INDIVIDUALs).ToList();
                result.StartTracking();
            });
        return result;
    }
```

Nothing to special: if there is a expression, get all individuals with this filter, otherwise return all.
The problem now: I wanna include another table for ONE case. So my thoughts: There should be an optional parameter, which I can add tables I wanna include with. So I dont need x functions for the same entitiyset but can dynamically add all the tables I want to include.

Do you think something like this is possible? Does this even makes sense? Or is it better to call the facade for each entitiy I need?

Thanks for your response!

Matthias Müller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just call the Entity Framework directly, each time you need the database, rather then using a facade. Otherwise you'll end up adding Order, Take functions as parameters as well, and your little method will end up getting bigger and bigger.

Just of interest, why are you even using the Facade? Is there some change in the future that you change your data access layer?

Comment: We're using a facadeproxy für webservice purposes. So there is no direct possibility to access the datalayer. Dynamically Including Tables would be a great feature, wouldnt it be?

Comment: If your using web services, why does the Expression logic need to come from the client? Shouldn't business logic stay on the server?

Comment: Yeah, but I need the entities to load the textboxes in the GUI. So instead of reading INDIVIDUAL and COUNTRY, I could just include COUNTRY to INDIVIDUAL. But I guess its not possible then.